# How to use WebBackgrounder when using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I am using task parallel library's `Parallel.ForEach()` to carry out some back ground tasks.
I came across Phil Haack's WebBackGrounder application. I wanted to implement it, but the `DoWork` method of `JobHost` supports only `Threading.Task` and not the action. Any idea about how to use it in context of `Parallel.ForEach` will be very useful.  Or else should I write my own class to handle the actions.

My Parallel Each method is as below:

```
IList<object> tasks = FetchActiveTasks();

OrderablePartitioner<Tuple<int, int>> chunkPart = Partitioner.Create(0, tasks.Count(), NoOfPartitions);

Parallel.ForEach(chunkPart, chunkRange =>
{
    for (int i = chunkRange.Item1; i < chunkRange.Item2; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!state.IsExceptional)
            {
                PerformTask(tasks[i]); // Method that carries out actual work.
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exceptions.Enqueue(e);
        }                  
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What does `WebBackGrounder` do and why are you trying to use it?

Comment: Is the parallel foreach really necessary when you're offloading the long running task into the background?

Comment: What is the question?  Does the posted code fail?  If so where?

Comment: I have different back ground tasks to be carried out in the application. Like when ever user clicks on one button we have series of operations to be carried out. For this we are using data base table as a queue to update tasks. Then in the background task, we select fixed number of tasks and using Parallel.ForEach we delegate the tasks. I want to use webBackGroundWorker for each task created, so that when the app domain stops, data is not lost. Hope this approach is proper.